# Get memory usage of a webapp without catalina resources in jProfiler

Tags: tomcat, web-applications, jprofiler

I'm using jProfiler to figure out how much memory is being consumed by my webapp. I've written a simple "Hello World" app and launched using Tomcat, attached jProfiler to the jvm and was surprised to see so much memory usage.

Screenshot: https://i.stack.imgur.com/YlRVr.png

I guess the memory usage shown is due to catalina consuming resources. Any idea how to find out actual usage by my webapp, without memory consumed by catalina?

Answer (score 0):

You have to use the heap walker in JProfiler to find out how the String objects are referenced.

Select java.lang.String in the "Classes" view of the heap walker and create a new object set
Then, switch to the "Cumulated incoming references" view and follow the large bars.